# Isolating a float value in a .csv file

Tags: c#, .net, csv, streamreader

I stumbled upon a little coding problem. I would like to read a .csv file and handle its data as float numbers (for changing some parameters of an object), so I can use any single of the numbers of the .csv file separately. My code at this point can read the .csv file but I am unable to handle every number as float. How can I use isolate a value from a .csv to use it later in the program? The data file I use has 4 rows and 100 lines.  My code at this point is this (it can only read the data from the .csv file):

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.IO;
    
    public class mag_rotation : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            ReadCSVFile();      
        }
    
        void ReadCSVFile()
        {
            StreamReader strReader = new StreamReader("D:200119200120.csv");
            bool endOfFile = false;
            while(!endOfFile)
            {
                string data_String = strReader.ReadLine();
                if (data_String == null)
                {
                    endOfFile = true;
                    break;
                }
                var data_values = data_String.Split (',');
            }
        }
        void Update()
        {
            
        }
    }
```

For example, from the data below:

```
0,17.02241,-4.793719,4.5759873,0
1,17.394623,-4.112285,3.5357802,0
2,17.713495,-2.6983683,3.3584955,0
3,17.106792,-5.2200847,4.727033,0
4,19.82562,3.1341507,3.834365,0
5,19.019388,1.9219573,5.6495733,0
6,18.546461,1.6253153,6.850214,0
7,17.545639,4.703565,7.0512614,0
```

I want to isolate the value in the second row, in the first line, 17.02241, and use it as a float later in the program.

Comment: What does "I am unable to handle every number as float" mean?  Are you looking for `float.Parse()`/`float.TryParse()`?  Can you provide some sample CSV data?  You're not handling any of the fields of each record but rather just `Split()`ing and throwing them away.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I edited my initial post with an example for clarification

Comment: All of those values could be parsed as a `float`, and the `0`s could be parsed to an `int`/`short`/`byte`.  Typically every value in the same column would have the same data type, so that's up to you to decide which is which, although there's no header line so it'd have to be done by index.  If this isn't an academic/learning exercise then you might consider just using a library for this.  [FileHelpers](https://www.filehelpers.net/) is a popular one.  Regarding the edit, is it always the value in the second **column** of the first row you want?

Comment: I'm sorry my description is problematic. To explain my problem in a single sentence, I would like to isolate certain values of a .csv file to use them later. I tried to handle the.csv file as a matrix but it seems this is the wrong way to do it For example, in a matrix (e.g. with the name "data) you can write data[0][1] if you want to isolate one item of a 2D matrix at the place [0][1] . So I would like to find a way to do this. Also, is there any way to do it without using a .NET library?

Comment: If the desired value is always the second value in the first record then that's as simple as `float.Parse(data_String.Split(',')[1])` with no surrounding loop.  If the column or row can change then you'll need to account for that (e.g. looping until the target row is read), plus whatever error handling.

Comment: The is not always a specific value in the .csv. For example, with a loop I want to change the record and read a new value from a row. What I need is to know how to read this value and store it into a variable

Comment: Well read them as strings. Split them into the individual chunks as indicated. And if it contains "." Then its a float of else those would be integers so what exactly is the probelm?

Comment: These are details you need to include in the question. You can load the CSV into a two-dimensional array or a jagged array or a collection of some custom data type or even a `DataTable`, or you can just grab the one value you want as the file is read and discard the rest.  We don't know what logic you're applying here, though, so I can't offer much more than the basic snippet in my last comment. Also, I notice in the original question you first used "rows" where I think you meant "columns"; to be clear, columns increase horizontally and rows, which occupy a full line, increase vertically.